# overflow property of stack in Flutter is not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
var stack = Stack(
  alignment: const Alignment(0.0, 2.0),
  overflow: Overflow.clip,
  children: [
    Image.asset('images/pic.jpg'),
    Image.asset('images/pic2.jpg'),
  ],
);
```

i set the value of overflow to Overflow.clip.but the pic2 is still visible.

Comment: Of course `pic2` is still visible. You explicitly display `pic2` on the top of `pic` with your code. What do you want  to do ?

Comment: The docoment said that overflowing children will be clipped to the bounds of their parent.after i set alignment to (0.0,2.0), the pic2 is outside of the stack.it should be cliped and not visible.

Comment: In flutter 3.0.1, overflow property is removed, instead set clipbehaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The `overflow` property only affects positioned widgets .

Answer (score 0):

use clipBehavior: Clip.none intead of overflow property